# Commenting a comment block

Tags: php, comments

I have a PHP code with a comment block:

```
function foo()
{
    $bar = true;
    /*
        Foo and bar do shopping
    */
    // and bars goes back alone
    return $bar;
}
```

Now, I want to comment the whole function, so I put it in a comment block:

```
/*
function foo()
{
    $bar = true;
    /*
        Foo and bar do shopping
    */
    // and bars goes back alone
    return $bar;
}
*/
```

And obviously, comment stops at the first `*/`.
Currently, I change the `/*` and `*/` to `/+` and `+/` in order to escape them.

```
/*
function foo()
{
    $bar = true;
    /+
        Foo and bar do shopping
    +/
    // and bars goes back alone
    return $bar;
}
*/
```

But I need to switch it back to `/*` and `*/` when I want to un-comment the whole function.

If I use `//` comments, using Ctrl+q shortcut from Notepad++, code lines switches to comment, and comment switches to code so function becomes:

```
// function foo()
// {
    // $bar = true;
    // /*
        //Foo and bar do shopping
    //*/
    and bars goes back alone
    // return $bar;
// }
```

**Is there a prettier way to escape `*/` comment ending tag in a comment block?**

Comment: php.net: 'C' style comments end at the first */ encountered. Make sure you don't nest 'C' style comments. It is easy to make this mistake if you are trying to comment out a large block of code.

Comment: You may use // to comment one single line.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the situation you've outlined, there is no 'prettier' way to do this.

Comment: Personally, when commenting blocks of code, I select them in Notepad++ and hit Ctrl+K. This prefixes each line with the appropriate line comment for the current language.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Oh, I didn't see the Ctrl+k stuff, I'll go for it, thanks. And so, even if it's now useless, there's no way to escape `*/`?

Answer (score 0):

do :
You can use # for function / line description

```
/*

##############
# Description
##############
function sampleFunction(){

}


*/
```

Comment: Oh, I like that, I'll just reverse it (use `#` commenting to put the whole function & comments on hold instead of `/*` `*/`). Does Notepad++ have a way to prepend a block of lines with `#`? Like a Ctrl+q or Ctrl+k but using `#`?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you don't think that [commenting the code is a bad practise](http://blog.codinghorror.com/coding-without-comments/), a nested comment could be a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell):

1. be sure no unneeded comments are in place;
2. use *SCM* (as you probably are already doing, such as Git or Subversion), commit frequently and don't be afraid of deleting the code instead of commenting it (you always can do a `revert` or a `reset`, and recover the previous commits).

Comment: If I had the right tools, I would do javadoc-comment-less code. For code-comments, commenting a block is useful when I want to do upgrade a function/method. I don't want to commit every 10 seconds to keep a track of original functions. I don't want to commit a code with a function I'm not sure of.